# what is the difference between __deref_out_opt and __deref_opt_out?

Tags: windows, annotations, static-analysis, microsoft-sal

What is the difference between the following [SAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383701%28VS.85%29.aspx) annotations?

```
void foo(__deref_out_opt PSTR* bar);

void foo(__deref_opt_out PSTR* bar);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PSTR*` out parameter means the caller passes in a buffer which receives a pointer to a string.

In __deref_out_opt, the string is optional (the function puts NULL in the caller-provided buffer).

In __deref_opt_out, the buffer is optional (the caller passes NULL to indicate disinterest in the output value).

Presumably, it's possible to combine these concepts, there should be a `__deref_opt_out_opt` modifier for that.

Comment: Where do I put the _opt for the "other case" where the function may set the output parameter to NULL?

Comment: After `out`, as in `__deref_out_opt`.  The SAL documentation describes the case of `__deref_opt` specially, and in that case the buffer may not exist.  You want the buffer to exist, hence plain `__deref`, but the pointer stored in it can be NULL, hence `_out_opt`.